# Setup a launch task in VS Code within a subfolder

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, gulp

My workspace folder structure is as follows:

> **main_folder**
>
> > **offline_unit**
> >
> > > gulpfile.babel.js
> >
> > **online_unit**
> >
> > **test_unit**

I am able to setup launch.json only in the main_folder, **how do I set it up inside offline_unit?**

I have tried moving .vscode folder to within offline_unit, didn't work.

The launch.json looks like this

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [ 
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Gulp task",
            "program": "/usr/local/bin/gulp",
            "args": [
                "build"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: A few years ago now when this was asked, but workspaces do work for me where I can have each subfolder added to the workspace.  Each subfolder can have its own launch.json and tasks.json - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces.  Each json file is contextual to its own folder - so ${workspaceFolder} would be contextual to that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work in a slightly elaborate way, using the following `launch.json`:

```
...
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Gulp task",
    "program": "/usr/local/bin/gulp",
    "args": [
        "--gulpfile",
        "offline-processor/gulpfile.babel.js",
        "build"
    ]
}
...
```

Specifying the global `gulp` as the program, and using `--gulpfile` to specify the path of my nested `gulpfile.babel.js`

Any better way to do this?

Comment: I hit a similar issue with a `preLaunchTask` of type `npm`. I found a sub-optimal solution - define this in the task: `"script": "--prefix my/sub/folder my_npm_script"`