# Set Subfolder for NPM Launch Task in VSCode

Tags: npm, vscode-debugger

Similar to what is listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130726/setup-a-launch-task-in-vs-code-within-a-subfolder).

I have a monorepo with multiple projects hosted under the same root directory and I was using VSCode as my editor. Instead of running/serving/testing through the terminal I wanted to use the VSCode Launch tasks to do this for me.

I copied over the launch recipes for Angular projects from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/Angular-CLI).

My issue was that I needed these tasks to run in the sub-directory they were associate with, including the pre-task.

Answer (score 1):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@Cam](/u/8384981)'s question post.

> for `launch.json` just append to the end of `"webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}[sub-dir]"` the sub-directory required.
>
> Then you also need to fix the **preLaunchTask** by altering the `tasks.json`.
>
> Thanks to Brandon Donnelson in [his video here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-sMmxfNxBM) showing the use of
>
> ```
> "options": {
>     "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/[sub-dir]"
> },
> ```
>
> Adding this after `problemMatcher` in `tasks.json` will have the tasks running in the sub-directory of your choice. This will of course make the sub-dir global for all projects in the monorepo and to combat this you can just move the `"cwd": "..."` to a task, make a copy of it and alter it for another project.